# Circle-valued Morse function and minimal genus

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, morse-theory

I think the following two statements are true, and most likely are in the literature. If so, could someone point me to some references? If not, counterexamples?

1. Let $Y$ be a closed oriented connected 3-manifold, and $[\theta]\in H^1(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ be a primitive class. Then a minimal genus embedded surface representing the Poincar'e dual of $[\theta]$ may be chosen to be connected. (Here, the embedded surface has "minimal genus" if $\chi_-(\Sigma):=\max (-\chi(\Sigma),0)$ is minimal among embedded surfaces representing the same homology class.)
2. In the preceding context, suppose $\theta=df$ where $f$ is a circle-valued Morse function with no local extrema. Then one of the regular level surfaces of $f$ is a minimal genus embedded surface representing the Poincar'e dual of $[\theta]$.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) yes.  If the fiber of the map $Y \to S^1$ is not connected, you simply tube the fibers together.  Regarding (2), I am not certain how you can interpret a cohomology class as the derivative of a function to the circle.

Comment: @Ryan Budney: Thanks! For (2): Think of the circle as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, then given $f: Y\to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $df$ is a closed 1-form.

Comment: By "no extrema" I suppose you mean no critical points that are local extrema?   Because it's unclear what extrema means for circle-valued functions.    Off the top of my head I don't see how to come to conclusion (2) for an arbitrary circle-valued Morse function, but one can certainly come to the conclusion in the homotopy-class of $f$.     Is that not enough for your purposes?

Comment: Yes, I should have said "local extrema". I don't know what "the conclusion in the homotopy class of $f$" means, but I need that the fiber of $f$ with minimal $\chi_-$ (among all fibers of $f$) has the minimal $\chi_-$ among embedded surfaces representing the same homology class.

Comment: i.e. if you are comfortable working with a map simply homotopic to $f$, then yes the conclusion holds.  The idea is to apply step (1) to a fiber, and then go in reverse to construct a new map $\tilde f$, homotopic to $f$, whose fiber is exactly your tubed-together manifold from step (1).

Comment: Thanks! But I actually don't understand what you said about (1) either. There is no $f$ in (1). Are you constructing one starting from a surface with minimal $\chi_-$ in the class $[\theta]$ somehow? If "tubbing" means internal connected sum, it would increase $\chi_-$ unless one of the components is a sphere.

Comment: I'm thinking about the cohomology class as a homotopy-class of map $Y \to S^1$.   If the map is transverse to a point in $S^1$, it's pre-image is the surface representing the Poincare dual.   If the surface isn't connected, you tube  it together and then reconstruct a homotopic map $Y \to S^1$ using the normal bundle of the connected surface i.e. the Pontriagin construction.  That's roughly how I'm thinking about your problem.

Comment: But such a surface may not have the minimal $\chi_-$ among its homology class.

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is no. There are primitive homology classes of aspherical closed 3-manifolds where the smallest Thurston norm is only realized by disconnected surfaces. On the other hand, you can realize circle valued Morse functions where the minimal genus is not achieved. Eg there are pretzel knots with incompressible Seifert surfaces of arbitrarily large genus (maybe realized by Casson-Gordon originallly?). I’ll try to come back here later and post an answer.

Comment: @Ian Agol Thanks so much! Please do come back! I would appreciate references/more details of the counterexamples.